# how do I mark coins spent in invalid blocks as unspent?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, regtest, chain-reorganization

I was just testing bitcoin (v17) in regtest mode with the local, built-in wallet. If I send money to an address (I don't own), generate 1, and then invalidate that block, the local wallet does not mark the coin spent in the invalid block as unspent. It keeps it in the spent state. Rolling back further, generating more blocks on a different chain, and rescaning the transactions doesn't seem to mark that money as unspent again. How do I respend my coin when it was spent in an invalid chain? From the local wallet CLI, is there a way to mark things as unspent?

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with Bitcoin Core's wallet itself and not something that you are doing wrong.